# Angular 4.4.6 animation transition doesn't happen

Tags: angular, animation, transition

I'm trying to add a very simple animation to my Angular 4.4.6 app. When the animation is triggered the transition to the new CSS style is instantaneous. I can see the new CSS properties, but there is no animated transition between the 2 states.

I'm stuck on this by hours!

I also enabled polyfill *web-animations-js*

**App module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
```

**My component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-anim',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './test.component.css' ],
  animations: [
    trigger('collapse', [
      state('open', style({ width: '*' })),
      state('close', style({ width: 0 })),
      transition('open => close', [
        style({ width: '*' }),
        animate(2000, style({ width: 0 }))
      ]),
      transition('close => open', [
        style({ width: 0 }),
        animate(2000, style({ width: '*' }))
      ])
    ])
  ]
})
export class TestComponent implements AfterViewInit  {
  isOpen = true;
  get collapseState() {
    return this.isOpen ? 'open' : 'close';
  }

// REST OF THE COMPONENT
```

**HTML template**

```
<button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
<h2>Without AnimationBuilder:</h2>
<div class="container" [@collapse]="collapseState"></div>
```

**Package.json**

```
"@angular/animations": "4.4.6",
"@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/common": "4.4.6",
"@angular/compiler": "4.4.6",
"@angular/core": "4.4.6",
"@angular/forms": "4.4.6",
"@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.12",
"@angular/http": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.4.6",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.4.6",
"@angular/router": "4.4.6",
"@liwebcorp/tron": "1.0.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.7",
"browserslist": "^2.4.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "2.5.1",
"highcharts": "^6.0.3",
"jquery": "^3.2.1",
"ng2-auto-complete": "0.12.0",
"ng2-bootstrap-modal": "^1.0.1",
"ng2-daterangepicker": "2.0.7",
"ng2-drag-drop": "2.9.2",
"ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
"ng2-tooltip-directive": "^1.2.3",
"ngx-file-drop": "^2.0.4",
"ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "^1.3.1",
"popper.js": "1.12.9",
"rxjs": "5.5.2",
"web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
"zone.js": "0.8.17"
```

Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
style({ width: '*' })
```

isn't a valid width and likely reverts to `auto` or `initial` when it's actually rendered in the browser. And `auto` isn't included in the css transition specifications. You need to set it to a value (likely 100)

```
style({ width: 100 })
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried your solution, but it doesnt work. I also tried to animate other CSS properties (i.e. opacity) but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

In your html template, try to switch your `isOpen` flag.

```html
<button (click)="isOpen=!isOpen">Toggle</button>
<h2>Without AnimationBuilder:</h2>
<div class="container" [@collapse]="collapseState"></div>
```

In your component, remove style from transition and animate.

```js
animations: [
  trigger('collapse', [
    state('open', style({ width: '*' })),
    state('close', style({ width: 0 })),
    transition('open => close', [
      animate(2000)
    ]),
    transition('close => open', [
      animate(2000)
    ])
  ])
]
```

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)